# Microphone works even though it is disabled in the Device Manager

Tags: windows-10, laptop, microphone, device-manager

I'm running Windows 10, and I have a microphone that I do not want to use.

I disabled the microphone in the Device Manager. When I checked, I found that it still worked. My laptop has no other microphones.

Why does the disabled microphone still work?

[image: Device Manager]

Comment: Have you tried disabling it in the Sound Settings? Task-bar -> right click on Speaker Icon -> select Recording Devices -> right click on microphone -> select Disable.

Comment: When I do to sound settings and set: Do not use this device, it doesn't work anymore. But why disable in device manager doesn't turn it off?

Comment: When pressing Properties in the recording device properties (see image https://i.imgur.com/TEqEJ8p.png) and going to the Driver tab does it show the same driver name?

Comment: Yes, the same driver there

Comment: If it's a built-in mic and you also have a microphone jack or headset jack, then maybe the device shown in the control panel is just for the jack. I'm not sure if or how a built-in mic would appear in device manager as a separate device, or if there may be a built-in webcam device that has its own microphone.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three way to enable or disable microphone(https://windowsreport.com/re-enable-microphone-pc/), we can try to choose any of them to disable microphone, then we go to see if microphone  still works.  If any of them does not work, the microphone has an independent drive, and the notebook keyboard also has a button to control the microphone, we can try to turn off the microphone using the hardware button. If the hardware can turn it off, the software can't turn it off. It may be a sound card driver problem. It is recommended that we download the sound card driver of the corresponding operating system on the official website, we need to reinstall the sound card driver, and uninstall the original sound card driver before reinstallation.